# cakephp3.0 Authentication

Tags: authorization, cakephp-3.0

Hey In authentication of cakephp3.0 I am facing some problem Hey how can i create an authentication based on patient table and patient controller like url/patient/login I have controller and model and form ready but when I go to login page it always search for query from usertable by default when I am trying to add this code in Patientcontroller :

```
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
AuthComponent::ALL => ['userModel' => 'Members'],
'Basic',
'Form']);
```

I am getting this error :

Error: Class 'App\Controller\AuthComponent' not found 
File D:\xampp\htdocs\hwapp\src\Controller\PatientController.php 
Line: 34``

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: I have read the documentation but I am unable to find the way I am stuck I need to restrict pages like patient controller and login through patient controller

Answer (score 0):

Please read this section of the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers

It explains how to use other table for handling login and how to tell the AuthComponent to use anther controller and action to handle the logic.